# I have an issue with Firebase error code 401

Tags: json, lua, firebase-authentication, roblox

So recently I'm trying to make a GlobalBan script for my admin module in ROBLOX, but I came across an error when I tried to do GlobalBan.

Below is the error and script:

```lua
local defaultDatabase = "Private";
local authenticationToken = "Private"

local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService");
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService");

local FirebaseService = {};
local UseFirebase = true;


--== Script;

function FirebaseService:SetUseFirebase(value)
    UseFirebase = value and true or false;
end

function FirebaseService:GetFirebase(name, database)
    database = database or defaultDatabase;
    local datastore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore(name);
    
    local databaseName = database..HttpService:UrlEncode(name);
    local authentication = ".json?auth="..authenticationToken;
    
    local Firebase = {};
    function Firebase.GetDatastore()
        return datastore;
    end
    
    function Firebase:GetAsync(directory)
        local data = nil;
        
        --== Firebase Get;
        local getTick = tick();
        local tries = 0; repeat until pcall(function() tries = tries +1;
            data = HttpService:GetAsync(databaseName..HttpService:UrlEncode(directory and "/"..directory or "")..authentication, true);
        end) or tries > 2;
        if type(data) == "string" then
            if data:sub(1,1) == '"' then
                return data:sub(2, data:len()-1);
            elseif data:len() <= 0 then
                return nil;
            end
        end
        return tonumber(data) or data ~= "null" and data or nil;
    end
    

    function Firebase:SetAsync(directory, value, header)
        if not UseFirebase then return end
        if value == "[]" then self:RemoveAsync(directory); return end;
        
        --== Firebase Set;
        header = header or {["X-HTTP-Method-Override"]="PUT"};
        local replyJson = "";
        if type(value) == "string" and value:len() >= 1 and value:sub(1,1) ~= "{" and value:sub(1,1) ~= "[" then
            value = '"'..value..'"';
        end
        local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
        replyJson = HttpService:PostAsync(databaseName..HttpService:UrlEncode(directory and "/"..directory or "")..authentication, value,
            Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationUrlEncoded, false, header);
        end);
        if not success then
            warn("FirebaseService>> [ERROR] "..errorMessage);
            pcall(function()
                replyJson = HttpService:JSONDecode(replyJson or "[]");
            end)
        end
    end
    
    function Firebase:RemoveAsync(directory)
        if not UseFirebase then return end
        self:SetAsync(directory, "", {["X-HTTP-Method-Override"]="DELETE"});
    end
    
    function Firebase:IncrementAsync(directory, delta)
        delta = delta or 1;
        if type(delta) ~= "number" then warn("FirebaseService>> increment delta is not a number for key ("..directory.."), delta(",delta,")"); return end;
        local data = self:GetAsync(directory) or 0;
        if data and type(data) == "number" then
            data = data+delta;
            self:SetAsync(directory, data);
        else
            warn("FirebaseService>> Invalid data type to increment for key ("..directory..")");
        end
        return data;
    end
    
    function Firebase:UpdateAsync(directory, callback)
        local data = self:GetAsync(directory);
        local callbackData = callback(data);
        if callbackData then
            self:SetAsync(directory, callbackData);
        end
    end
    
    return Firebase;
end

return FirebaseService;
```

Error Code:

[image: 1]

```
23:50:36.033  TestService: Data table for bans is currently nil.  -  Studio  
23:50:36.255  FirebaseService>> [ERROR] HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)  -  Studio
```

I have tried to create new database + renewing my auth token, still getting Error code 401.
I feel like its my auth token issue but at the same time I don't think it is either, hope you guys can help me figure out the error. Feel free to ask if you need more info regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my auth token was the wrong one, everything's good now